# Scrollbar centralizando sozinha

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho um form com altura maior que a tela, com muitos botoes e checkboxes, O usuário usa a barra de rolagem para rolar pra baixo e ver todo o conteúdo do form.

Meu problema é que toda vez que o usuário tenta clicar em um botão ou checkbox, o form tentar centralizar esse botão no meio da tela do usuário, rolando a barra de rolagem sozinho. Isso atrapalha demais, as vezes ta lendo alguma coisa e precisa ativar um botão, o form tenta centralizar esse botão e rola a barra de rolagem, as vezes faz com que o usuário até perca o clique e tem que clicar denovo.

Vi que isso é o comportamento padrão da propriedade `Autoscroll = true`; Porem se mudo pra `Autoscroll=false`, a barra de rolagem desaparece.

Existe um jeito de corrigir isso? Uso visual studio 15, winforms

Comment: Porque que o form centraliza o botão?

Comment: Isso, eu não quero que o panel tente centralizar o item clicado, rolando a barra de rolagem sozinha. Quero q a barra de rolagem fique onde o usuario a deixou, mesmo se o botao que ele vai clicar está bem no canto da tela.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente é o comportamento padrão do *scroll*, disparar o evento `ScrollToControl` passando o controle que foi clicado.

Você pode sobrescrever este evento no contêiner de seus elementos, retornando `DisplayRectangle.Location`.

```
protected override Point ScrollToControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control activeControl)
{
    return DisplayRectangle.Location;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo, mas não entendi direito como implementar esse código que passou. Aonde eu digito esse código?

Comment: Como eu disse, precisa sobrescrever o evento no controle que é container dos elementos. Se os elementos estão soltos no form, precisa colocar no form. Se eles estão num painel, precisará criar uma nova classe herdando de `Panel`, escrever este método e depois alterar o seu painel atual pra o que foi criado.